# Mageto2 product listing page random product

Tags: magento2

when we refresh the product listing page , it always show the random position for the products. we set the default sort by the position and did not assign any position to products for this category.
what could be wrong ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default under these circumstances it should return a list of products by entity_id unless filters are specified.

Comment: I tried with removing all custom modules and default theme , but it is still behaving like this , can it be because of upgrading Magneto. I have tried installing the fresh version with sample data and everything seems to be working fine on fresh install.